# Deleting the character "Â" from the database

Tags: php, mysql, database

For some reason, I have an invalid character "Â" in my database.

When I look for the character "Â", it searches it as a regular "A".

How can I delete all the instances of "Â"?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Try `REPLACE INTO yourTable (column) VALUES ('Â', '')`

Comment: @Fred-ii- How sure are you that the character is actually there and not, for example, some character encoding issue with PhpMyAdmin, MySqlWorkbench or some other tool or even Lanbo's "page" (see PHP tag)? Who's to say what Lanbo sees is what's actually there? How sure are you it's safe to simply replace that Â? How sure are you it's safe to replace **all** Â's for that matter (because that's what you're doing). I wouldn't be so sure...

@ glenatron See the tags: MySql

Answer (score 4):

> For some reason, I have an invalid character "Â" in my database.

No, not "for **some** reason". Go read "[The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)". You will then understand that "some" reason and why you, most probably, **don't** want to delete that character or, if you still want to delete it, you'll at least know what you're doing and what the risks are of deleting that character.

If you still want to replace "the character":

```
update `mytable` set `somefield` = replace(`somefield`, 'Â', '<replacement>')
```

This will do a full table scan/update; you might want to be more specific like:

```
update `mytable` set `somefield` = replace(`somefield`, 'Â', '<replacement>')
where `some_id` in (1, 4, 7, 92, 2973)
```

or...

```
update `mytable` set `somefield` = replace(`somefield`, 'Â', '<replacement>')
where `somefield` like '%Â%' collate utf8_bin
```

Where, in above examples, you'd replace `<replacement>` with the desired char or `''` to "delete" it.

You'd probably want to read up on [charsets and collations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset.html) (which is why I pointed you to Spolsky's post in the first place, because you'll have to understand the basics) and then decide if you want to use, for example, a [case-sensitive (_cs), case-insensitive collation (_ci) or binary (_bin)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-mysql.html) for your query and **which** collation.

Comment: Although this provides good reference material related to the question, it does not answer the question itself.

Comment: @rink.attendant.6: So, worth attracting a -ve ??

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 : I'm tired of this argument. Go read [Question quality is dropping on Stack Overflow](https://pay.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/24vitp/question_quality_is_dropping_on_stack_overflow/). I don't care if it answers the question: `Give a man a fish and feed him for a day, teach a man how to fish and feed him for a lifetime`.

Comment: It does now. Everybody happy?

Comment: When I try to search the database for "Â", it perceives it as a normal "a" and tries to delete all the normal "a"s..

Comment: That is because you didn't [read the frikkin' article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) and didn't take a look at [the links I provided](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset.html) and because you don't specify which collation to use in your query.